# How to select one field from view in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

How can do the following query in MySQL?

```
Select SUM(T1.Amount) 
From 
( 
  Select  Distinct PersonName,Amount 
  From  tblusers as T1 
  where city ="xxx"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL requires an alias on a derived table or subquery.  So you will want to use the following:

```
Select SUM(t1.Amount) 
From 
( 
  Select Distinct PersonName, Amount 
  From  tblusers
  where city ="xxx"
) t1
```

You should be able to use the following though depending on your needs:

```
select personName, sum(Amount)
from tblusers
where city = "xxx"
group by personName
```

Or if you just want to return the sum, you can use:

```
select sum(Amount)
from tblusers
where city = "xxx"
group by personName
```

Answer (score 2):

Just alias the subquery:

```
Select SUM(Amount) 
From (
    Select Distinct PersonName, Amount 
    From  tblusers 
     where city ="xxx")  t
```

And if you're looking for each person, add a GROUP BY:

```
Select PersonName, SUM(Amount) 
From (
    Select Distinct PersonName, Amount 
    From  tblusers 
     where city ="xxx")  t
Group By PersonName
```

If you really want the sum of each person (and not the sum of the distinct person/amount), then you don't need the subquery at all:

```
Select PersonName, SUM(Amount) 
From tblusers 
Where city ="xxx"
Group By PersonName
```

Depends on your actual needs though.

Comment: @KESAVANPURUSOTHAMAN -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 0):

I done it with below query.But wants to know is there any other possible way to do it.

```
    CREATE VIEW  T1 as (Select  Distinct PersonName,Amount From  tblusers  where city ="xxx" );

     Select SUM(Amount) From  T1
```